Fujifilm Finepix Z200fd pictures not loading correctly
Today when I was taking pictures with my camera, some of the pictures came out pixelated or blurry on the lcd screen and I thought they would eventually load and come out clear. I went to upload my pictures to my laptop and found that some of them looked like this. Would I be able to salvage these pictures or are they gone forever? You can kind of make them out on the lcd screen, but they don't show up at all when I connect my camera to my laptop. I included a picture of what the pictures would look like on my laptop when I connect my camera to it. 

Note that it's common for digital photos to embed a low-resolution thumbnail within the file itself. The camera may display the thumbnail image on its screen, rather than read the full image file - so you can have a situation where the larger image file has become corrupted, but the thumbnail is still intact and readable.

Worth mentioning another possibility - the camera records a low-resolution thumbnail either as a standalone file on the memory card, or in a (proprietary?) database file somewhere. Again, the camera may use this thumbnail for display on the LCD screen, while the real full-res image file has become corrupted.

There's an interesting utility available called JPEGsnoop, and its now-defunct homepage had some useful explanatory information on corrupt JPEGs.

For me these images are broken.

one reason can be broken SD card. What you can do is to format the card (in camera!) and make test again (take photo, transfer to PC, visualize). If the result is the same replace the card.
can be problem with transfer. Change cable, transfer files again. Also take new photos and try to transfer them. You can try also not to connect camera, but read the card via reader.

P.S. You can try some file recovery software, but my personal experience show the chance of success is minimal.
P.P.S. If none of above help maybe it's time to change the camera (at the end this is 16 years old model)
